# Oracle average difference between two date fields

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, rdbms

I have a table in database like this:

```
unit arrival_date               departure_date
---- -------------              --------------
1    27/1/2017 08:01:20 a. m.   27/1/2017 08:04:27 a. m.
1    27/1/2017 08:05:35 a. m.   27/1/2017 08:09:28 a. m.
```

I need to calculate the average time difference between arrival_date and departure_date of users and show the result as hour,minute,second format(HH:MI:SS).

If I made this `arrival_date - departure_date`, I get the result in days, but I am struggling to get the average in hour, minutes and seconds.

The fields are `DATE` fields not `TIMESTAMP` fields.

Comment: execute the query and let me  know???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.

When subtracting two date datatype values, the result is number of days. It shows the `INTER` CTE. When you multiply it by 24 (number of hours in a day), 60 (number of minutes in an hour) and 60 (number of seconds in a minute), the result is number of seconds (`DIFF_SECS`).

`AVERAGES` CTE shows how to apply `AVG` function to previous results; nothing *special* in that, just pay attention that you have to `GROUP` it `BY` the `UNIT` column.

Finally, apply `TO_CHAR` formatting to calculation (some `TRUNC` and `MOD` calls in order to extract hours, minutes and seconds from the `AVG_DIFF_SECS` value).

I suggest you run each CTE separately, step by step, to easier follow the execution.

```
SQL> with test (unit, arr, dep) as
  2    (select 1, to_date('27.01.2017 08:01:20', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  3               to_date('27.01.2017 08:04:27', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi:ss')
  4     from dual union all
  5     select 1, to_date('27.01.2017 08:05:35', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  6               to_date('27.01.2017 08:09:28', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi:ss')
  7     from dual
  8    ),
  9  inter as
 10    (select unit, (dep - arr) diff_days,
 11       (dep - arr) * 24 * 60 * 60 diff_secs
 12     from test
 13    ),
 14  averages as
 15    (select unit,
 16       avg(dep - arr) avg_diff_days,
 17       avg((dep - arr) * 24 * 60 * 60) avg_diff_secs
 18     from test
 19     group by unit
 20    )
 21  select
 22    to_char(trunc(avg_diff_secs / 3600), 'fm00') || ':' ||           -- hours
 23    to_char(trunc(mod(avg_diff_secs , 3600) / 60), 'fm00') || ':' || -- minutes
 24    to_char(mod(avg_diff_secs, 60), 'fm00')                          -- seconds
 25    avg_diff_formatted
 26  from averages;

AVG_DIFF_FORMATTED
--------------------
00:03:30

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select unit, avg(departure_date - arrival_date) as avg_date
from mytable
```